# NDVI mean in polygon between dates, for a set of polygons

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time-series

I have a set of stations, each has a start and end date for consideration, and polygon of interest.
For each station, I need to average the NDVI inside the polygon, and then to average the NDVI for all images between the two dates.

I'm trying to:

1. Import Landsat, polygons.
2. Map over the polygons.
3. For each polygon from 2., filter Landsat for the date range, and polygon.
4. Map NDVI on the filtered result of 3.
5. Map-reduce NDVI from 4. to the polygon by `reduceRegion`.

Here I'm not sure how to average over the polygon and then over the time span.
Before moving forward, I would like to know if the process makes sense.

```
var cohort = ee.FeatureCollection("users/miki98k/temp");
var l7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2");


var results = cohort.map(function(feature){
  var sdate = ee.Date(feature.get('start_date'))
  var edate = ee.Date(feature.get('end_date_a'))
  var roi = feature.geometry()

  var filt_img = l7
      .filterDate(sdate,edate)
      .filterBounds(roi)
      .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 100);

  var ndvi_func = function (i) {
  var ndvi = i.normalizedDifference (['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return i.addBands(ndvi)
  }
  
  var image_ndvi = filt_img.map(ndvi_func)

  var reduced = image_ndvi.map(function(image){
    return image.reduceRegion({
      geometry:roi,
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      scale: 30
    });
  });
  
  return reduced
  })

print(results)
```

Comment: You should try to follow this with a  mean reducer for the polygon-reduced features

Answer (score 1):

Your approach makes sense, more or less.

There is an error in the script: `reduceRegion()` returns an `ee.Dictionary`, but the function mapped over a collection must return an `ee.Image` or `ee.Feature` (it can return collections too).

If I understood your question correctly, you want a single mean value per polygon, a mean both across the date range and the polygon. If that's the case, you should calculate the date range mean before calculating the polygon mean. It'd be significantly more efficient. Something like this:

```
// var cohort = ee.FeatureCollection("users/miki98k/temp") // You didn't share your asset
var cohort = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([10, 0]).buffer(1000), {start_date: '2020-01-01', end_date_a: '2020-04-01'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([11, 0]).buffer(1000), {start_date: '2020-01-01', end_date_a: '2020-04-01'})
])

var l7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2")
var results = cohort.map(calculateMean)
print(results)


function calculateMean(feature) {
  var sdate = ee.Date(feature.get('start_date'))
  var edate = ee.Date(feature.get('end_date_a'))
  var roi = feature.geometry()

  var filt_img = l7
    .filterDate(sdate, edate)
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 100)

  var ndvi_func = function(i) {
    var ndvi = i.normalizedDifference(['SR_B5', 'SR_B4']).rename('NDVI')
    return i.addBands(ndvi)
  }

  var mean_ndvi = filt_img.map(ndvi_func)
    .select('NDVI') // Only NDVI band is needed
    .mean() // Mean accross the date range - reduces the image collection into a single image
  return ee.Feature(
    feature.geometry(), 
    mean_ndvi.reduceRegion({ // Mean over the roi
      geometry: roi,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 30
    })
  )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c3a2fc4fbc28aab524552c4738e716e7